# How to merge two objects with duplicated key sumup value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two objects as follows:

```
const a = {
  '2021-1': 10,
  '2021-2': 8
}
const b = {
  '2021-1': 10,
  '2020-3': 10,
  '2020-4': 15,
  '2020-5': 12,
  '2020-6': 4
}
```

I would like to merge two objects and sum up values for duplicated keys.

Expected result is:

```
{
  '2021-1': 20,
  '2021-2': 8,
  '2020-3': 10,
  '2020-4': 15,
  '2020-5': 12,
  '2020-6': 4
}
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: can you attach the solution how i can get the result either using pure javascript or lodash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform a reduce operation over the entries of the second object to sum the values of each key, using a copy of the first object as the initial value.

```js
const a = {
  '2021-1': 10,
  '2021-2': 8
}
const b = {
  '2021-1': 10,
  '2020-3': 10,
  '2020-4': 15,
  '2020-5': 12,
  '2020-6': 4
}
const res = Object.entries(b).reduce((acc,[k,v])=>{
  acc[k] = (acc[k] || 0) + v;
  return acc;
}, {...a});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

This utility function merges the two objects and sums conflicting keys, including all the values unique to either `a` or `b`.

```js
const mergeWithSum = (a, b) =>
  [...Object.keys(a), ...Object.keys(b)].reduce((combined, key) => {
    combined[key] = (a[key] ?? 0) + (b[key] ?? 0);
    return combined;
  }, {});

const a = {
  '2021-1': 10,
  '2021-2': 8
}
const b = {
  '2021-1': 10,
  '2020-3': 10,
  '2020-4': 15,
  '2020-5': 12,
  '2020-6': 4
}

console.log(mergeWithSum(a, b));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @soimon but this doesnt work properly. "2021-1" should be 20

Comment: @WilliamWang you are right, I forgot the parenthesis. I've corrected it, but as the accepted answer by iota is functionally equal it is trivial which approach you go with.

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution

```js
function mergeObj(obja, objb) {
    const merged = {...obja};
    for ([key, value] of Object.entries(objb)) {
        if(merged.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           merged[key] = merged[key] + value
        } else {
           merged[key] = value
        }
    }
    return merged
}
```

it uses a simple for of loop, from object.entries and we destructure the array that contains key and value